# Cython constructor overloads in .pxd file error: "Self argument of C method does not match parent type" for factory function

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I'd like to have several ways of constructing a `cdef class` in Cython, but I can't figure out how to use factory functions with extension classes that would be exportable to other modules using .pxd files.

The [Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#existing-pointers-instantiation) has the following example with factory functions, which works as expected when I compile it:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

# Example C struct
ctypedef struct my_c_struct:
    int a
    int b


cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.ptr_owner = False

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # De-allocate if not null and flag is set
        if self._ptr is not NULL and self.ptr_owner is True:
            free(self._ptr)
            self._ptr = NULL

    # Extension class properties
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._ptr.a if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._ptr.b if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner=False):
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects from
        given my_c_struct pointer.

        Setting ``owner`` flag to ``True`` causes
        the extension type to ``free`` the structure pointed to by ``_ptr``
        when the wrapper object is deallocated."""
        # Call to __new__ bypasses __init__ constructor
        cdef WrapperClass wrapper = WrapperClass.__new__(WrapperClass)
        wrapper._ptr = _ptr
        wrapper.ptr_owner = owner
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass new_struct():
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects with
        newly allocated my_c_struct"""
        cdef my_c_struct *_ptr = <my_c_struct *>malloc(sizeof(my_c_struct))
        if _ptr is NULL:
            raise MemoryError
        _ptr.a = 0
        _ptr.b = 0
        return WrapperClass.from_ptr(_ptr, owner=True)
```

However, when I try to break out the cdef declarations into a .pxd file like this:

WrapperClass.pxd

```
ctypedef struct my_c_struct:
    int a
    int b

cdef class WrapperClass:
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner

    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner)
    cdef WrapperClass new_struct()
```

WrapperClass.pyx

```
# cython: language_level=3

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.ptr_owner = False

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # De-allocate if not null and flag is set
        if self._ptr is not NULL and self.ptr_owner is True:
            free(self._ptr)
            self._ptr = NULL

    # Extension class properties
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._ptr.a if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._ptr.b if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner=False):
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects from
        given my_c_struct pointer.

        Setting ``owner`` flag to ``True`` causes
        the extension type to ``free`` the structure pointed to by ``_ptr``
        when the wrapper object is deallocated."""
        # Call to __new__ bypasses __init__ constructor
        cdef WrapperClass wrapper = WrapperClass.__new__(WrapperClass)
        wrapper._ptr = _ptr
        wrapper.ptr_owner = owner
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass new_struct():
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects with
        newly allocated my_c_struct"""
        cdef my_c_struct *_ptr = <my_c_struct *>malloc(sizeof(my_c_struct))
        if _ptr is NULL:
            raise MemoryError
        _ptr.a = 0
        _ptr.b = 0
        return WrapperClass.from_ptr(_ptr, owner=True)
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
WrapperClass.pxd:9:30: Self argument (my_c_struct *) of C method 'from_ptr' does not match parent type (WrapperClass)
```

Is it not possible to use static classes as a "class method" for an extension that can be cimported into another module? This sample code is a stand-in for a larger project I'm working on where I'd like to have multiple ways of constructing a cpp Cython class, some of which would use cpp data structures as arguments (which the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#existing-pointers-instantiation) notes can only be done using factory functions).

Comment: Have you tried putting the `@staticmethod` in the pxd file too? That's an important part of the signature as far as Cython is concerned.

Comment: @DavidW adding `@staticmethod` to the pxd file worked to solve that error, but for whatever reason, the minimal example then raised the error `Signature not compatible with previous declaration`, but after some trial and error, I found that that is due to the second argument `bint owner` rather than the pointer being wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, found this thread, and the last missing piece was in the [comment by DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453298/cython-constructor-overloads-in-pxd-file-error-self-argument-of-c-method-does/73467541#comment115719162_65453298).

As for the `bint owner` problem, I did something that made the compiler tell me to replace the default argument with either `?` or `*`.

So, the complete files are:

```
ctypedef struct my_c_struct:
    int a
    int b

cdef class WrapperClass:
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner=*)

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass new_struct()
```

and:

```
# cython: language_level=3

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.ptr_owner = False

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # De-allocate if not null and flag is set
        if self._ptr is not NULL and self.ptr_owner is True:
            free(self._ptr)
            self._ptr = NULL

    # Extension class properties
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._ptr.a if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._ptr.b if self._ptr is not NULL else None

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner=False):
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects from
        given my_c_struct pointer.

        Setting ``owner`` flag to ``True`` causes
        the extension type to ``free`` the structure pointed to by ``_ptr``
        when the wrapper object is deallocated."""
        # Call to __new__ bypasses __init__ constructor
        cdef WrapperClass wrapper = WrapperClass.__new__(WrapperClass)
        wrapper._ptr = _ptr
        wrapper.ptr_owner = owner
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass new_struct():
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects with
        newly allocated my_c_struct"""
        cdef my_c_struct *_ptr = <my_c_struct *>malloc(sizeof(my_c_struct))
        if _ptr is NULL:
            raise MemoryError
        _ptr.a = 0
        _ptr.b = 0
        return WrapperClass.from_ptr(_ptr, owner=True)
```